# NoClassDefFoundError when class is already declared in the same java file

Tags: java, android, exception

I have a class declared in the same java file for my android project and my code for some reason is not recoginizing it? I get a NoClassDefFoundError at runtime when I go to run it in the emulator.

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my android application in the emulator:

```
01-16 19:58:41.394: E/dalvikvm(2648): Could not find class 'nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.overlay.AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay', referenced from method nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.overlay.AsyncOverlay.<init>
01-16 19:58:41.394: W/dalvikvm(2648): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 939 (Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay;) in Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay;
01-16 19:58:41.394: D/dalvikvm(2648): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0044
01-16 19:58:41.394: W/dalvikvm(2648): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentMapQuestOverlay; (562)
01-16 19:58:41.394: W/dalvikvm(2648): Link of class 'Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentMapQuestOverlay;' failed
01-16 19:58:41.404: W/dalvikvm(2648): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mapquest/android/maps/Overlay;)
01-16 19:58:41.404: W/dalvikvm(2648): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay; (1422)
01-16 19:58:41.404: W/dalvikvm(2648): Link of class 'Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay;' failed
01-16 19:58:41.414: W/dalvikvm(2648): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/osmdroid/views/overlay/Overlay;)
01-16 19:58:41.414: W/dalvikvm(2648): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay; (1422)
01-16 19:58:41.414: W/dalvikvm(2648): Link of class 'Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay;' failed
01-16 19:58:41.427: D/dalvikvm(2648): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x16f6 at 0x4e in Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay;.<init>
01-16 19:58:41.434: W/dalvikvm(2648): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentMapQuestOverlay; (562)
01-16 19:58:41.434: W/dalvikvm(2648): Link of class 'Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay$SegmentMapQuestOverlay;' failed
01-16 19:58:41.434: D/dalvikvm(2648): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x16f2 at 0x55 in Lnl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/map/overlay/AsyncOverlay;.<init>
01-16 19:58:41.468: D/AndroidRuntime(2648): Shutting down VM
01-16 19:58:41.474: W/dalvikvm(2648): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.overlay.AsyncOverlay$SegmentOsmOverlay
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.overlay.AsyncOverlay.<init>(AsyncOverlay.java:92)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.overlay.BitmapSegmentsOverlay.<init>(BitmapSegmentsOverlay.java:23)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.LoggerMapHelper.onCreate(LoggerMapHelper.java:195)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at nl.sogeti.android.gpstracker.viewer.map.GoogleLoggerMap.onCreate(GoogleLoggerMap.java:90)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-16 19:58:41.514: E/AndroidRuntime(2648):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 19:59:01.474: W/Trace(2666): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Here is my code:

```
AsyncOverlay(LoggerMap loggermap, Handler handler)
{
  mLoggerMap = loggermap;
  mHandler = handler;
  mWidth = 1;
  mHeight = 1;
  mPaint = new Paint();
  mActiveZoomLevel = -1;
  mActiveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  mActiveTopLeft = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
  mActivePointTopLeft = new Point();
  mCalculationBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  mOsmOverlay = new SegmentOsmOverlay(mLoggerMap.getActivity(), mLoggerMap, this);
  mMapQuestOverlay = new SegmentMapQuestOverlay(this);
}
```

Here is my class:

```
   static class SegmentOsmOverlay extends org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay {
   AsyncOverlay mSegmentOverlay;
  LoggerMap mLoggerMap;

  public SegmentOsmOverlay(Context ctx, LoggerMap map, AsyncOverlay segmentOverlay)
  {
     super(ctx);
     mLoggerMap = map;
     mSegmentOverlay = segmentOverlay;
  }

  public AsyncOverlay getSegmentOverlay()
  {
     return mSegmentOverlay;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e, org.osmdroid.views.MapView openStreetMapView)
  {
     int x = (int) e.getX();
     int y = (int) e.getY();
     GeoPoint tappedGeoPoint = mLoggerMap.fromPixels(x, y);
     return mSegmentOverlay.commonOnTap(tappedGeoPoint);
  }

  @Override
  protected void draw(Canvas canvas, org.osmdroid.views.MapView view, boolean shadow)
  {
     if (!shadow)
     {
        mSegmentOverlay.draw(canvas);
     }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the name of the Java file?

Comment: Is the .class file in the proper location in the directory structure?  (Corresponding to it's `package`.)

Comment: What are access modifiers for the class?

Comment: You can use the `dexdump` tool on your APK to verify that the class is actually included in the packaged app.  Also, is it possible that it is the OSMDroid superclass that is absent and that is why it can't load the class?

Comment: Hassan TM - the name of the file is AsyncOverlay.java

Comment: @user268397 If `AsyncOverlay.java` is static then why it doesnt have `static` in front of it. I will also suggest to make them `public`

Answer (score 0):

try to clean your project (project --> clean..)
and then refresh your project (right click on project name --> refresh..)

le me know if it worked.